# Problem using .Value in LINQ query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This is probably something extremely simple but I can't get my head around it so help would be appreciated :)

I have a simple XML file that I'd like to parse and I have a problem accessing element's values.

This is the XML document I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[ This is the description of the application. ]]>
    </description>    
    <parameters>
        <param type="int32" name="testvar1" required="false">10</param>
        <param type="string" name="testvar2" required="true" />
        <param type="float" name="testvar3">42.00</param>
    </parameters>
</application>
```

I load the document from a textbox, like:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

And I use a simple Linq query to filter out stuff:

```
var parameters = from param in doc.Descendants("param")
                 select new
                 {
                     name = (String)param.Attribute("name"),
                     type = (String)param.Attribute("type"),
                     value = (String)param.Value, // Wrong?
                 };

var data = String.Empty;
foreach (var p in parameters)
{
    data += p.name;
    data += " -- ";
    data += p.type;
    data += " -- ";
    data += p.value;
    data += "\n\r";
}
```

The output looks like:

```
testvar1 -- int32 -- 
testvar2 -- string -- 
testvar3 -- float --
```

In other words, the line `value = (String)param.Value` doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

**EDIT:** It seems like I wasn't reading the correct XML file, my bad. The question below is still valid though...

Also, the following lines causes a NullReferenceException:

```
var description = (String) doc.Element("description").Value;
```

So it looks like I don't quite understand how to get the value of XML elements :) Could you help me fix these?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having problems with:

```
var description = doc.Element("application").Element("description").Value;
```

or

```
var description = doc.Element("description").Value;
```

but this one seems to work:

```
var description = doc.Descendants("description").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`XElement.Value` is [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx) so doesn't require neither cast `(string)` nor `ToString()`.

---

Use

```
doc.Element("application").Element("description").Value
```

to get description value

---

```
foreach (var p in parameters)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name={0} type={1} value={2}", p.name, p.type, p.value);
}
```

outputs next:

```
name=testvar1 type=int32 value=10
name=testvar2 type=string value=
name=testvar3 type=float value=42.00
```

so your code works to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with or without the cast I still don't see any output.

Comment: I did try that before, still a NullReferenceException :(

Comment: @Hamza: Your xml works to me properly. Check what do you type in the textbox

Comment: Yup, copy/paste error. Sorry for taking your time! (Although the Element("description") still throws exceptions)

Comment: Seems like `doc.Descendants("description").First().Value` works fine.

Comment: You can't use `doc.Element("description")` as the description element is not a child of the document, it is a descendant of the document. It is a child of the application element so the already suggested `doc.Element("application").Element("description")` should do. If you still get an exception then somehow the input you use is not as posted.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange because I just ran your code and got

> testvar1 -- int32 -- 10
>   testvar2 -- string --
>   testvar3 -- float -- 42.00

with or without the String cast of `param.Value`

to get the description you could do

```
doc.Element("application").Element("description").Value;
```

Comment: Sorry about that, it seems like I've picked the wrong XML file when I ran the program, that bit works now. I've tried your suggestion for the 'description' but that didn't work. I've posted a working solution below. Thanks.